# Enumeration with direct and indirect properties

Tags: word-usage

I have an enumeration where two of the things (technology and size) refer directly to the energy plant and the third (duration) only indirectly:

> Die Höhe der Förderung ist abhängig von der Technologie und Größe der Anlage und der bereits geförderten Dauer.

Is there a better way to write it without using `und` twice?

Comment: Slight edition .. I would choose "der bereits geförderten Menge" .. as the time usually doesn't play a role (you can dig there for 200 years - and only dig out say one small heap per week - or you dig for 5 years and fill whole trains consisting of 30 units of 60 ton carriages twice per day ... do you still think that time is of importance in your writing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't have **an** enumeration. You have **two** enumerations. There is an outer enumeration:

> Anlage und Dauer

And for the first item you have a list of properties that form an inner enumeration:

> Technologie und Größe (der Anlage)

If you put them together, you get encapsulated enumerations. For each of them you need an *»und«* between the penultimate and the ultimate item of the enumeration. This is equal in English:

> The amount of funding depends on the technology and size of the facility and the duration already funded.

Outer enumeration:

> facility and duration

Inner enumeration:

> technology and size (of the facility)

If you want to use only one *and/und* you must get rid of the encapsulated enumerations. This means you have to bring them on the same level:

> The amount of funding depends on the technology of the facility, the size of the facility and the duration already funded.

Now you have technology, size and duration at one level, which means, you now can put a comma between the first and the second item.

Same in German:

> Die Höhe der Förderung ist abhängig von der Technologie der Anlage, der Größe der Anlage und der bereits geförderten Dauer.

---

Another trick is what πάντα ῥεῖ mentioned in [his answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55377/enumeration-with-direct-and-indirect-properties/55378#55378): Use a synonym

In English:

> The amount of funding depends on the technology and size of the facility **as well as** the duration already funded.

In German:

> Die Höhe der Förderung ist abhängig von der Technologie und Größe der Anlage **sowie** der bereits geförderten Dauer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer :)

Comment: And now you have only one *und* ... but two times *Anlage*.

Comment: @Olafant: There is no optimal solution (and, btw, nobody asked for one)

Comment: You're right. OP only asked for a better way, not for an optimal solution. Btw., I think the sentence with *sowie* is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 5):

Man könnte auch alternativ formulieren

> Die Höhe der Förderung ist abhängig von der Technologie **, sowie der** Größe der Anlage und der bereits geförderten Dauer.

Comment: Thank you. I find the use of `sowie` somewhat unclear. Is it also possible to write:  `Die Höhe der Förderung ist abhängig von der Technologie und Größe der Anlage, sowie der bereits geförderten Dauer.`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it is more idiomatic to put the **»sowie«** to connect the last term of enumerations.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In most cases this is correct, because this is the most frequently used order in such embedded enumerations.To be more precise however, I would say that the *"sowie"* should replace the *"und"* of the **outer** enumeration; so if the Dauer comes first it would turn into `(...) abhängig von der bereits geförderten Dauer sowie der Technologie und Größe der Anlage`. This becomes an even stronger effect if we have one outer and **two** inner enumerations: `(...) abhängig von der Technologie und Größe der Anlage, sowie der bereits geförderten und der noch verbleibenden Dauer.`

Comment: @MerklT In all use cases I can think of *sowie* is identical  in meaning and use to the english expression *as well as*.

Comment: When used as a replacement for "und" there is typically no comma before "sowie".

Comment: This proposal collapses the two enumerations (see Huberts answer) into one. This would, however, be more commonly phrased by not inserting *sowie* but just using the separating comma.

Answer (score 3):

Hubert's answer is quite detailed, but "bring[ing] them on the same level" doesn't sound very nice because you repeat "der Anlage".

I would say the best way to do it is using synonyms like πάντα ῥεῖ did with "sowie".

You can find more synonyms here: https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/und.php

Keep in mind you change the word order/phrasing with some synonyms.

More examples:

> **Zusätzlich** zu der Technologie und Größe der Anlage ist die Höhe der Förderung (auch) von der bereits geförderten Dauer abhängig.
>
> **Neben** der Technologie und Größe der Anlage ist die Höhe der Förderung (auch) von der bereits geförderten Dauer abhängig.

If the sentence gets too complicated you can always split it up into two sentences:

> Die Höhe der Förderung ist abhängig von der Technologie und der Größe der Anlage. **Auch** die bereits geförderte Dauer spielt eine Rolle/ist für die Förderung entscheidend.